# map URLs ending with .html to URLs without extension using mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi I want to map my existing URL that end with .html to map to URL that don't have extension

In summary I want

```
http://something.com/apps/my-app.html
```

this to map to

```
http://something.com/apps/my-app/
```

but the URL in the address bar should not be changed, I guess that can be done using PT flag

Answer (score 0):

Try this in root dir,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule apps/([\w-]+).html apps/$1/ [L]
```

Comment: Hi but isn't this reverse of what I want, wouldn't this map url like apps/ to /apps.html. What I want is the URL in address bar should contain .html extension but on server it should access the one without extension

Comment: Please try the edit I assume your original url is working.